# How can I "exploit" in Elder Scrolls Online and what does it do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Whenever someone else is attacking an enemy, I sometimes get a message on the screen that says

> Hold (Right Mouse Button Icon) to Exploit

What does that mean exactly and what does it do?

What are the effects of "exploiting" in this case?

Comment: Leave my nice catchy little google baiting title. Thanks.

Comment: To be fair, it's a poorly worded title.

Comment: "How can I exploit?" Well...you even say it right in the question body. Hold the right mouse button. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Exploiting" is a game mechanic that will essentially knock-down/stun an opponent.

To performan a successful exploit, you'll **first** have to get your enemy into **off-balance** (e.g. by blocking a heavy attack or disrupting a cast). Once that happens, you're able to perform a **heavy attack** (doesn't have to be fully charged) to exploit their weakness, resulting in the mentioned stun/knockdown.

Comment: I often stun enemies when I am fighting alone, but never saw this message. Does this work when you are fighting on your own or this a coop action only, if I can use that term?

Comment: It always works. The message you're talking about is one of the tutorial/combat tips. By default they won't show again, unless you (re-)enable them in the options.